# htmlunit vs. jwebunit with htmlunit plugin

Tags: testing, user-interface, htmlunit, jwebunit

I did some research on ui testing tools such as `htmlunit`, `httpunit`, `jwebunit`, `selenium` etc.

I'm not very familiar to testing tools. `Htmlunit` sounds a good option in terms of javascript support. Then, I found `jwebunit`, it provides APIs and it is possible to write concise code using `jwebunit` compared to `htmlunit`.

The one thing I'm not very sure: When we use `jwebunit` with `htmlunit` plugin, do we have all features of `htmlunit`, or does `jwebunit` limits usage of some features provided by `htmlunit`?

Answer (score 0):

For UI testing there is another interesting choice: use Cannoo Webtest(based on HtmlUnit) + Groovy language. You can write your tests using simple DSL, for example(from [official site](http://webtest.canoo.com/webtest/manual/WebTestHome.html)):

```
import com.canoo.webtest.WebtestCase

class SimpleTest extends WebtestCase {
  void testWebtestOnGoogle() {
    webtest("check that WebTest is Google's top 'WebTest' result") {
      invoke "http://www.google.com/ncr", description: "Go to Google (in English)"
      verifyTitle "Google"
      setInputField name: "q", value: "WebTest"
      clickButton "I'm Feeling Lucky"
      verifyTitle "Canoo WebTest"
    }
  }
}
```